# Selenium - Search multiple keywords in Google after each other v2

Tags: selenium

Selenium - Search multiple keywords in Google after each other

**Java - Selenium - Search multiple keywords in Google after each other.**

I actually want to perform a search on Google with Selenium (or a search field on a website), whereas the input is a list of keywords say:

I want to search on Google:

1. Keyword: a
2. then Keyword: b
3. then Keyword: n
4. then Keyword: x

How do I actually automate this? I cannot find anything useful.. I saw something about dictionaries which you can set up, but not in practice.

So Search Google -> for a list of keywords (a, b, n, x)

Any help would be awesome!

what i did sofar:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
public class GoogleSearch

{

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\xx\\Software\\selenium_browser_drivers\\Chrome86\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://google.com/");
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).sendKeys("My Search Text");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(2000);


        List<WebElement> links =   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='res']//a/h3"));
        int count = links.size();

        System.out.println(count);
        for (int i =0;i<count;i++)

        {

            String linkname = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='res']//a/h3")).get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(linkname);

        }

        getScreenshot();

    }

    public static void getScreenshot() throws IOException

    {

        File src= ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        FileHandler.copy(src,new File("C:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\google.png"));

    }

}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to search for `a` the reload google.com and search for `b` and so on?

Comment: yeah indeed that is basically what i want to achieve :D